# Ubuntu 16.04 Keeps Logging Into Temporary Guest Account

Tags: 16.04

A few weeks ago, I let a friend run code in MATLAB on my Linux distribution; however, it was having troubles running the code and started acting fairly slow. Hence, restarted my computer and it started logging me into a temporary guest session. When I restart and login, it keeps taking me to the temporary guest session. Moreover, if I try switch accounts, it again takes me into the guest session. Unfortunately, I cannot access root because the temporary guest session prevents me from being capable using sudo. I am not necessarily sure how to go about troubleshooting this issue, as I am fairly new to Linux and there does not seem to be a lot of individuals who have had this particular issue. Hence, I am curious if anyone has an idea how I can resolve my predicament.

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Can you log into your regular non-guest account via one of the CLI virtual terminals (Ctrl-Alt-F1 thru Ctrl-Alt-F6)?

Comment: If his Xenial is like my Xenial, that is actually F2 - F6 now. F1 seems to be where the gui lives now, instead of F7 like it used to. I'm assuming that was a change made by Canonical, and not just some weird thing I did in installing.

Comment: @steeldriver I am capable of accessing the virtual terminal via Ctrl-Alt-F1

Answer (score 0):

The solution is actually quite simple (embarrassingly). One can either access the CLI virtual terminal from the temporary guest account, then simply create another account. From this account one has access to root and hence is capable of reverting back to the old administrative account.